# Using SVM under Adaboost

Tags: svm, adaboost

I have a set of svm classifiers that i would like to train under adaboost. Is there any library avaiable for download that implements an adaboost algorithm that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is a Java library that has an implementation of Adaboost.